# How to analyse data received in advertising packet from BLE for Ionic Application?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, bluetooth-lowenergy

Advertising data is in readable format for iPhone, but it is in decimal format for android. How to read and interpret the advertising packet for android.

```
 this.scanner = this.ble.scan(["00EDSE-0000-00AE-9VVQ-9125475145125"], 1).subscribe((response) => {
              console.log("success scan.." + JSON.stringify(response));
              this.ble.connect(response.id).subscribe((response) => {
                this.toast.show("Successfully paired", '2000', 'bottom').subscribe((toast) => {
                  console.log(toast);
                  this.spinnerDialog.hide();
                });
```

Comment: please post your code

Comment: I have added the code @MaximShoustin